# Connection string entity framework 6.0 mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, connection-string

Hi I used Visual Studio 2010 with entity framework 4.0 and now I export my project in visual studio 2013 with entity framewok 6.0. I see my database model and the web project work fine (my pages can read and write the database) but when I try to upload my model from the database I obtain this error

System.ArgumentException while updating Model from Database my error is"Impossible convert the connection string"

My connection string is

```
metadata=res://*/db_test.csdl|res://*/db_test.ssdl|res://*/db_test.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password=root;database=db_test;Persist Security Info=True"
```

Comment: Check if you have two identical nodes for EntitySetMapping. If you do remove one and it should be fine.

Comment: Where I find the EntitySetMapping?Thanks